# Capture Gridview SelectedIndexChanged using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I have ***Master Page ---> Content Page ---> User Control ---> Gridview***

How do I capture the Gridview `SelectedIndexChanged` event using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no client side event `OnSelectedIndexChanged`. You can, however, register a script in the Server side event handler:

```
protected void gridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "selectedIndexChanged", "javascriptFunctionCallHere();", true)
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: what if I wanted to pass arguments into this Function? How would I do that?